# Перезапустить setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

#### Описание

Создал что-то подобное функции вызывающийся в каждом кадре:

```js
class Program
{
    FramesCount = 60;
}
```

```js
setInterval
(
    function()
    {
        //Тут какие то действия
    }, 
    1000 / Program.FramesCount
);
```

Проблема в том что `Program.FramesCount` пользователь может изменить и в этот момент функция `setInterval()` должен выполнять те же самые действия только с новой задержкой.

---

#### Вопрос

Как можно это реализовать?

---

#### Дополнение

Я искал в интернете на эту тему, наткнулся только на `clearInterval`, но как после этого запустить `setInterval` снова я так и не нашёл. Так что как ответ можете кидать ссылки на полезные статьи и другие сайты.

Comment: Берёте и "перезапускаете", в чем проблема? `let intervalId = setInterval(action, 1000 / Program.FramesCount); clearInterval(intervalId); intervalId = setInterval(action, 1000 / Program.FramesCount);`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Именно так и попробовал, но случились усложнения с повтором действий так как изначальный `setInterval` была в другом скрипте а меняющая функция - в другом. Но решение участника `vsemozhebuty` уже решил проблему. Спасибо вам за внимание.

Comment: Вариант с ручным перезапуском здесь один из самых удачных, но я бы его организовал все же вне метода, занимающегося какой-то своей логикой. Он об организации цикла знать не должен. Можете обернуть setTimeout и сделать из него асинхронный sleep, после чего запустить цикл: `while (true) { draw(); await sleep(1000 / Program.FramesCount); }

Comment: @Kir_Antipov то что вы написали сверху звучит как фокус.) Я начинающий программист на Js и настолько далеко зашёл поскольку знаком с похожим языком (C#), но `async`, `await` и всё такое не изучил пока на Js :-)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не богохульствуйте и не называйте C# похожим на JS :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ну... чуть-чуть похоже.) У них дед общий))

Comment: Как человек, у которого вовсю идёт второй десяток лет стажа на шарпах, уверяю вас - ни капли не похожи :) Дед много у кого общий. У Эйнштейна и Леонардо Ди Каприо, например, тоже есть общий предок. И насколько они похожи? Ровно настолько, насколько каждый из нас похож друг на друга, человек на человека, язык на язык ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так, чтобы значение каждый раз считывалось заново:

```js
setTimeout(foo, 1000 / Program.FramesCount);

function foo() {
  setTimeout(foo, 1000 / Program.FramesCount);
  //Тут какие то действия
}
```

Альтернативы:

1. Связать перезапуск таймера с кодом, устанавливающим `FramesCount`.
2. Проверять текущее значение `FramesCount` с переменной, хранящей прежнее значение, внутри `foo` и перезапускать таймер при изменении.

Возможно, проще изменить упомянутый фрагмент, чем менять всё это окружение. Но если постоянный пересчёт таймаута повлияет на производительность (сомневаюсь, но мало ли), альтернатива 1 может быть самой щадящей с точки зрения производительности, хотя и добавит связанности коду.

Comment: Ловить момент не проблема так как `FramesCount` на самом деле не простая переменная а свойство. Спасибо за решение.

Comment: Если вы хозяин кода в `Program`, можно реализовать `FramesCount ` как сеттер и вставить туда логику перезапуска. Если такое связывание приемлемо.

Comment: Именно [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM17V.png) и делал. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто определить setInterval в функцию и вызывать её после сброса

```
function playInterval() {
    intervalId = setInterval(
        function() {
            //Тут какие то действия
            if (условие, при котором сбрасывается интервал) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    playInterval();
                }, 1000)
            }
        }, 
    ), 3000;
}

playInterval();
```